# String extraction?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to get "YYYY" from the string "XXXX · YYYY· ZZZZ"  using sed in a BASH .

Trying to understand sed better but I'm not getting it yet

Comment: Is each component always four characters, with the three groups separated by space dot space?

Comment: If the original string is kept in a variable in `bash`, there is no real reason to use `sed` as it would be more efficient to use two standard parameter expansions (trimming the prefix and then the suffix off from the string). Where do you store the string?

Comment: Yes it is. AWK would work better buy I am trying  to see if sed can do it.

Comment: In a variable for later use.

Comment: @αғsнιη it's 0xc2 0xb7, "middle dot"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the exact `sed` command you used. Also, please format the string as code (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) so we can be sure we are using the right one.

Comment: This page (https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) explains sed very well -
also it has a fantastic set of other unix tutorials
(https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/index.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `bash` there's no need to use either `awk` or `sed`

```
string='XXXX · YYYY· ZZZZ'
printf '%s\n' "${string:7:4}"
YYYY
```

The string is not particularly nice for processing with `sed`. If we assume that you've got `·`  as a prefix and `·` as a suffix you can pick it out like this

```
string='XXXX · YYYY· ZZZZ'
printf '%s\n' "$string" | sed -nE 's/^.*· ([^· ]+)·.*/\1/p'
YYYY
```

The ERE is fiddly though

```
^             # Bind to start-of-line
.*            # Any character, zero or more times
·             # Literal dot and space
(             # Start of a bracketed group
    [^· ]+    # NOT dot or space, at least once
)
·             # Literal dot
.*            # Any character, zero or more times

\1            # The value of the first bracketed expression
```

It's probably worth pointing out that the dot character used in this expression is not a decimal point / full stop on a standard keyboard; it's [middle dot](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B7), represented in UTF-8 as 0xc2 0xb7.

Comment: Th.is really helps me understand sed better. Thanks! Learning Klingon is easier than sed.

Comment: @Dark_Stoner `sed`, `grep`, and many other utilities rely on Regular Expressions. There are a number of different variants (BRE, ERE, PCRE) offering increasing levels of potential complexity, but the fundamentals remain similar throughout

Comment: Yes I realize I'd been overthinking things too much. When you have so many tools available, it's had for me not to use them.